# Select unique records and display as category headers in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sql-order-by

I have a rails 3.2 app running on PostgreSQL, and have some data I want to display in my view, which is stored in the database in this structure:

```
+----+--------+------------------+--------------------+
| id | name   | sched_start_date | task               |
+----+--------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | "Ben"  | 2013-03-01       | "Check for debris" |
+----+--------+------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | "Toby" | 2013-03-02       | "Carry out Y1.1"   |
+----+--------+------------------+--------------------+
| 3  | "Toby" | 2013-03-03       | "Check oil seals"  |
+----+--------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to display a list of tasks for each name, and for the names to be ordered `ASC` by the first `sched_start_date` they have, which should look like ...

```
Ben
2013-03-01 – Check for debris

Toby
2013-03-02 – Carry out Y1.1
2013-03-03 – Check oil seals
```

The approach I starting taking was to run a query for unique names and order them by `sched_start_date ASC`, then run a query for each name to get their tasks.

To get a list of unique names, the SQL would look like this.

```
select * 
from (
   select distinct on (name) name, sched_start_date 
   from tasks
) p 
order by sched_start_date;
```

I would like to know if this is the correct approach (querying for unique names then running another query for all their tasks), or if there is a better rails way.

Comment: I think your first problem is that your database seems not to be properly normalized. In addition to `tasks`, you should probably have a `mechanics` or `technicians` table where `Ben` and `Toby` are stored. Then, in `tasks`, instead of having a `name` column, have a `mechanic_id` column that references `mechanic`.

Comment: Then you can just do this: in your controller, set `@mechanics = Mechanic.all`, and then in the view, do `<% @mechanics.each do |mechanic| %><%= mechanic.name %><% mechanic.tasks.each do |task| %><%= task.description %><% end %><% end%>`. (I'd also recommend changing the `tasks.task` to, say, `tasks.description`.)

Comment: Oh, I meant to link this in my first comment: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have associations in your model you would be able to run

```
@employees = Employee.order(:name, :sched_start_date, :task).includes(:tasks)
```

You could then iterate over them:

```
@employees.each do |employee|
  employee.name
  employee.tasks.each do |task|
    task.name
  end
end
```

This isn't gonna exactly match your needs, but should show you where to start.

Comment: Yes, this is roughly the right thing to do. One difference will be that in a view, it will be ERB instead of straight Ruby, and I think a prerequisite to doing any of this stuff is to get your tables properly normalized, which from what I can tell they almost certainly are not yet.

Comment: I agree, improved normalization would definitely be a place to improve.

Comment: Thanks Jason, muttonlamb, Mischa. The data comes from an excel sheet so I thought it would be quicker to write a more complex query than change the parser, however I think I will take your advice and normalise my DB. I would still be interested, if you know how, in translating the SQL query in my Q to Active Record. Thanks again for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

To get the data sorted like you describe, you might want to use `min()` as [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT name, sched_start_date, task
FROM   tasks
ORDER  BY min(sched_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name), 1, 2, 3
```

Your original query would need an additional `ORDER BY` item to get the earliest date per name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, sched_start_date, task
FROM   tasks
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

I also added `task` (`3`) as last `ORDER BY` item to break ties, in case there can be more than one per date.

But the output is still ordered by `name`, not by `date`.

Getting your peculiar format with all data stuffed into one column is a bit more complex:

```
SELECT one_col
FROM  (
    WITH x AS (
        SELECT name, min(sched_start_date) AS min_start
        FROM   tasks
        GROUP  BY 1
        )
    SELECT 2 AS rnk, name
          ,sched_start_date::text || ' – ' || task AS one_col
          ,sched_start_date, min_start
    FROM   tasks
    JOIN   x USING (name)

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS rnk, name, name, NULL::date, min_start
    FROM   x

    ORDER  BY min_start, name, rnk, sched_start_date, task
    ) y
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, I didn't mean the output of the query had to be in 1 column, that's just how it would be rendered in ERB. Your answer is nonetheless interesting though. I'm trying to learn more raw sql so this is really valuable info. Thanks

Comment: @Chris: I can only work with what's actually *in* your question. It always helps to add an example of what the result should look like. Also, I added the missing task to my queries. And I added info about what's wrong with your original query.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Erwin, I would have up-voted your answer but I don't have enough rep.